# Odd Behavior when Calling Resource Controller from Unit Test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

routes.php

```
Route::resource('job.comment','PostCommentController');
```

PostCommentController::testComment()

```
$response = $this->route('POST','job.comment.store',array('this one is stripped' => 'why?','body' => "body","job_id" => $job->id));
```

When I dump Input::all(), that first parameter is not received. This was not a problem until I  upgraded the project to Laravel 4.1.* and doesn't appear to have affected any other tests.

Comment: Seems strange. Can you upgrade to the latest Laravel 4.2.* version and see if it happens there?